# google maps - open on appropriate appropriately sized map

Tags: api, google-maps

I want to use google maps in such a way that 
if user asks for "United States", then the map 
will open with setCenter of 2 0r 3.

but if he asks for "West Broadway NY"
then the map will automatically zoom into the neighborhood.

This works on google site, but it not obvious
how the API works.

Comment: see my example - http://tinyurl.com/ye5khug

Answer (score 0):

Using this [URL](http://maps.google.com/maps/empw?url=http:%2F%2Fmaps.google.com%2Fmaps%3Ff%3Dq%26source%3Ds_q%26hl%3Dfr%26geocode%3D%26q%3DWest%2BBroadway%2BNY%26sll%3D37.0625,-95.677068%26sspn%3D54.79724,107.578125%26ie%3DUTF8%26hq%3D%26hnear%3DW%2BBroadway,%2BNew%2BYork%26t%3Dh%26z%3D15%26ll%3D40.719692,-74.005931%26output%3Dembed&hl=fr), you'll directly go to "West Broadway NY". You can set the size and the zoom of the map.

In order to get this URL, go to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com/) and click on the "link" button on the top right. Then click on the "customize..." link.